# Creating Dynamic Text of File Names in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, actionscript, interactive

I have a large quantity of sounds I want to trigger through buttons in Flash. Rather than put text for name of each sound on every button, I was wondering if it's possible to write code on the button with a dynamic text box to inherit the file name of the sound but omit the .mp3 file ending. Is this possible?

P.S. I'm a noob at Actionscript so please bear with me.

Comment: It's certainly possible. Post the code you currently have relevant to this.

Comment: As @Aaron mentioned, it is possible and can be achieved in many ways. We find this question without proper requirement. What is your actual problem when you have not tried anything?